# Android - Making a Menu Bar appear after clicking in a list

Tags: android, click, menubar

So, im developing a mobile app and I ve this doubt that I hope someone can solve. I have a List with projects. What I want is, when I click in one of the projects, I dont want to go to another page, I just want to see like a toolbar right under the project I just clicked. My idea is to follow basically the same concept like the app Any.Do .

[Here](http://www.google.com/imgres?um=1&hl=pt-PT&sa=N&biw=1366&bih=643&tbm=isch&tbnid=9RPbcZMzBhS6RM:&imgrefurl=http://android.appstorm.net/reviews/productivity-reviews/any-do-helps-you-make-things-happen/&docid=lksoRGUDWLOCvM&imgurl=http://android.appstorm.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/AnyDO2.jpg&w=800&h=1280&ei=x56GT8TiF4SmhAf87cDRCA&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=402&vpy=107&dur=617&hovh=284&hovw=177&tx=106&ty=174&sig=111827409133443286618&page=1&tbnh=139&tbnw=100&start=0&ndsp=22&ved=1t:429,r:1,s:0,i:68) it is what I would like to do.

I would appreciate if someone could help me on this.

Comment: As Any.DO's Android developer, I can tell you that the way to do so was specified on my blog post: http://udinic.wordpress.com/2011/09/03/expanding-listview-items/ It's quite long to write it here, so it'll be better just to get all the info from there. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [QuickActionBar](http://greendroid.cyrilmottier.com/reference/greendroid/widget/QuickActionBar.html) from [GreenDroid](http://greendroid.cyrilmottier.com/) project.

Cyril has created a GDCatalog sample app ([available from the market](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cyrilmottier.android.gdcatalog)), which also [features this (src)](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid/blob/master/GDCatalog/src/com/cyrilmottier/android/gdcatalog/QuickActionActivity.java).

Comment: Its a great link. Can you give me a sample code? I think it would be easier to understand. thanks

Comment: Isnt there another QuickActionBar tht is included in Android SDK ?